# Inserting a multiline very long string into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, sql-insert

Can someone tell me how to insert a multiline passage (say a very big paragraph) into a MySQL database table using a shell script?

Here is the function that I'm currently using:

```
function dbPopulate()
{
    command_ouput=$1

    mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD << EOF
    use $DB_NAME;

    INSERT INTO $STATS_TABLE (script_runtime, command_output) VALUES (now(), $command_output);

    EOF            
}
```

Note: Here command_output is of type "longtext"

Comment: What about this isn't working? Does quoting your variables help/fix the problem? (You should essentially *always* quote your shell variable expansions.)

Comment: The text passage that is being passed has new lines in it.. special characters etc. so I think that collides with the syntax of the insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the string that you're trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO `$STATS_TABLE` (script_runtime, command_output) 
    VALUES (now(), '$command_output');
```

I also put some backticks around the table name that you're inserting into, which prevents your script from failing when the table name is a reserved keyword.